How to display Before and After Count Per Section with Pivot Table
I have a table in excel and am trying to show the the before and after total if people were to move to different section. The initial table has a emp number, region, job type, before section and after section.
I would like to have a pivot to show there were 10 people in the HR before section and now the after section showing 7 people and so on with other section changes. Ideally in the pivot I would like for it to show each section with a before and after columns i.e. Region, HR Before, HR After, IT Before, IT After etc with other section After/Before Numbers.
I would possible have two rows, so region and the job type under it as a sub row. The difficulty seems to be with getting two columns which are not nested and have there own count.
Sample Table
Emp No: Region: Role Type: Before: After

1 Europe Analyst HR IT 
2 Europe Dev IT IT 
3 Europe Support HR HR 
4 Asia Analyst HR IT 
5 Asia Support HR IT 

How I want data to look
Region: HR Before: HR After: IT Before: IT After 

Europe 2 1 1 2
Asia 2 0 0 2

Have tried pivot table but this seems to nest the columns together and the values then seem to be the same so not getting the accurate interpretation

You can use COUNTIFS to get your desired results.

This can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)
To use Power Query

Select some cell in your Data Table
Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range or from within sheet
When the PQ Editor opens: Home => Advanced Editor
Make note of the Table Name in Line 2
Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
Read the comments and explore the Applied Steps to understand the algorithm

let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Roles"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Emp No:", Int64.Type}, {"Region:", type text}, {"Role Type:", type text}, {"Before:", type text}, {"After", type text}}),

    Departments = List.Buffer(List.Sort(List.Distinct(#"Changed Type"[#"Before:"] & #"Changed Type"[#"After"]))),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Region:"}, {
            {"Before", (t)=>
                    Record.FromList(List.Transform(Departments, (d)=> List.Count(List.Select(t[#"Before:"], each _ = d))),
                        List.Transform(Departments, each _ & " Before:"))},
            {"After", (t)=>
                    Record.FromList(List.Transform(Departments, (d)=> List.Count(List.Select(t[After], each _ = d))),
                        List.Transform(Departments, each _ & " After"))}}),
    #"Expanded Before" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Before", {"HR Before:", "IT Before:"}),
    #"Expanded After" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Before", "After", {"HR After", "IT After"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded After",
        List.Transform(List.RemoveFirstN(Table.ColumnNames(#"Expanded After"),1), each {_, Int64.Type}))
in
    #"Changed Type1"


